# Custom buttons 'sometimes' cause null pointer

Tags: java, button, menu, enums

So I have been learning and experimenting with Java for just under a month so far. I'm currently experimenting with custom buttons (not jbuttons) changing enum states. 
For this test I have two classes which both have the exact same code (menu and settings)  with exception of the names and position of the buttons as well as what state they set on click.
Weirdly if I have menu as the starting state then I always get a null pointer error at this line of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if(options[i].intersects(new Rectangle(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY(), 1, 1))){
            currentSelection =i;
            clicked = Mouse.wasPressed(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
        }
    }
```

**BUT** if settings is the starting state then I can click back and forth through both buttons with no errors at all. 
As both menu and settings have the same code I'm at a loss as to why this error occurs.

Bellow I will post my classes involved in this button testing, In future would it be better to link a Github repository instead of posting full classes?

Thank you for any help you can give to solving this mystery!

Main class creates window and sets a state:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Base extends Canvas implements Runnable{   
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static int width = 800;
private static int height = 600;
public static String title ="<{[x]}>";

public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
private static Thread thread;
public static JFrame frame;
private static boolean running = false;
private Menu menu;
private Settings settings;

public static enum STATE{
    MENU, SETTINGS
};
public static STATE state = STATE.MENU;
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/    
public static void main(String[] args){                                 
    Base base = new Base();
    Base.frame.setResizable(true);
    Base.frame.setTitle(Base.title);
    Base.frame.add(base);                                               
    Base.frame.pack();
    Base.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Base.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Base.frame.setVisible(true);
    base.start();
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public Base(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame = new JFrame();
    settings = new Settings();
    menu = new Menu();
    Mouse mouse = new Mouse();
    addMouseListener(mouse);
    addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public void update(){
    if(state == STATE.MENU){
        menu.tick();            
    }
    if(state == STATE.SETTINGS){
        settings.tick();
    }
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public synchronized void start(){                                       
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/    
public synchronized static void stop(){                                     
    running = false;
    System.exit(0);
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(state == STATE.MENU){
        menu.init();
        menu.render(g);
    }
    if(state == STATE.SETTINGS){
        settings.init();
        settings.render(g);
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/    
public void run() {                         // The main game loop of the game.
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    requestFocus();
/*--------------------*/// Start of Game Loop.
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now-lastTime) / ns;   // Ensures only 60 updates per second.
        lastTime = now;
/*--------------------*/    
        while (delta >=1){          // Bellow things to update 60 times a second.
            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;     
            }                       // Bellow things to update as fast as possible.
        render();
        frames++;
 /*--------------------*/               // Bellow sets the updates per second and fps to the title bar.         
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer +=1000;
            frame.setTitle(title + " | " + updates + " ups, " + frames + " fps");
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
 /*--------------------*/// End of Game Loop.
    stop();
    System.exit(0); 
}
 /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public static int getWindowWidth(){
    return width;
}
public static int getWindowHeight(){
    return height;
}
}
```

Menu class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Menu {

private Button[] options;
private int currentSelection;

public Menu(){  
}

public void init() {
    options = new Button[1];
    options[0] = new Button("Settings", 300 ,300, new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 32), new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 48), Color.WHITE , Color.GREEN);
}

public void tick(){

    boolean clicked = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if(options[i].intersects(new Rectangle(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY(), 1, 1))){
            currentSelection =i;
            clicked = Mouse.wasPressed(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
        }
    }
    if (clicked)    select();
}

private void select(){
switch(currentSelection){
case 0:
    Base.state = Base.STATE.SETTINGS;
    System.out.println("Settings");
    break;
}
}
/*----------------Render Method----------------------------------------------------------------*/   
public void render(Graphics2D g) {

for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    if(i == currentSelection)
        options[i].setSelected(true);
    else options[i].setSelected(false);

    options[i].render(g);
}
}

}
```

Settings class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Settings {

private Button[] options;
private int currentSelection;

public Settings(){
}

public void init() {
    options = new Button[1];
    options[0] = new Button("Back",         300 ,200, new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 32), new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 48), Color.WHITE , Color.GREEN);
}

public void tick(){

    boolean clicked = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if(options[i].intersects(new Rectangle(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY(), 1, 1))){
            currentSelection =i;
            clicked = Mouse.wasPressed(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
        }
    }
    if (clicked)    select();
}

private void select(){
switch(currentSelection){
case 0:
    Base.state = Base.STATE.MENU;
    System.out.println("menu");
    break;
}
}
/*----------------Render Method----------------------------------------------------------------*/   
public void render(Graphics2D g){

for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    if(i == currentSelection)
        options[i].setSelected(true);
    else options[i].setSelected(false);

    options[i].render(g);
}
}

}
```

Button class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Button extends Rectangle{

static int Width = Base.getWindowWidth();
static int Height = Base.getWindowHeight();

private Font font, selectedFont;
private Color color, selectedColor;
private boolean selected;
private String text;
private int textY;
private int textX;

public Button(String text, int textY, Font font, Font selectedFont, Color color, Color selectedColor) {
    this.text = text;
    this.textY = textY;
    this.font = font;
    this.selectedFont = selectedFont;
    this.color = color;
    this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
}

public Button(String text,int textX, int textY, Font font, Font selectedFont, Color color, Color selectedColor) {
    this.text = text;
    this.textX = textX;
    this.textY = textY;
    this.font = font;
    this.selectedFont = selectedFont;
    this.color = color;
    this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    if(selected)
        Fonts.drawString(g, selectedFont, selectedColor, text, textX, textY);
    else
        Fonts.drawString(g, font, color, text,textX, textY);

    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    this.x = textX;
    this.y = textY - fm.getHeight();
    this.width = fm.stringWidth(text);
    this.height = fm.getHeight();
    //g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);

}

}
```

Fonts class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;



public class Fonts {

static int width = Base.getWindowWidth();
static int height = Base.getWindowHeight();

public Fonts(){

}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public static void drawString(Graphics g, Font f, Color c, String text, int x, int y){
    g.setColor(c);
    g.setFont(f);
    g.drawString(text, x, y);
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/    
public static void drawString(Graphics g, Font f, Color c, String text ){
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(f);

    int x = (width - fm.stringWidth(text))/2;
    int y = ((height - fm.getHeight())/2) + fm.getAscent();
    drawString(g, f, c, text, x, y);
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public static void drawString(Graphics g, Font f, Color c, String text, double x ){
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(f);

    int y = ((height - fm.getHeight())/2) + fm.getAscent();
    drawString(g, f, c, text, (int)x, y);
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
public static void drawString(Graphics g, Font f, Color c, String text, int y ){
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(f);

    int x = (width - fm.stringWidth(text))/2;
    drawString(g, f, c, text, x, y);
}

}
```

Mouse class:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

private static final int NUM_BUTTONS = 10;
private static final boolean buttons[] = new boolean[NUM_BUTTONS];
private static final boolean lastbuttons[] = new boolean[NUM_BUTTONS];
private static int mouseX = -1;
private static int mouseY = -1;
private static int mouseB = -1;



public static int getX(){
    return mouseX;
}
public static int getY(){
    return mouseY;
}

public static int getButton(){
    return mouseB;
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseB = e.getButton();
    buttons[e.getButton()] = true;

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseB = MouseEvent.NOBUTTON;
    buttons[e.getButton()] = false;

}

public static void update(){
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
        lastbuttons[i] = buttons[i];
}

public static boolean isDown(int button){
    return buttons[button];
}

public static boolean wasPressed(int button){
    return isDown(button) && !lastbuttons[button];
}

public static boolean wasReleased (int button){
    return !isDown(button) && lastbuttons[button];
}

}
```

Comment: You should do the work of paring down this code to only the most relevant parts.  Folks aren't going to want to go through all of this code.

Comment: `"Bellow I will post my classes involved in this button testing, In future would it be better to link a Github repository instead of posting full classes?"` -- do **neither**. Instead best would be to create a completely new small program for your question, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Comment: Also, if your problem is due to a NPE being thrown, then you will need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: It is the least amount of code that if copied to a compiler will give the the outcome I am experiencing.  Everything else I have stripped away.

Comment: If you don't get an answer soon, then you will want to keep stripping. I'm not sure about anyone else, but that's way too much code for me to wade through. Please remember that we're all volunteers and appreciate any effort you expend to make it easier to help you.

Comment: Your options array is null until init() is called. Are you trying to access the array before the method is called? Just guessing after glancing through this large amount of code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think this was the problem.  I added a call to the init method in the switch statement the buttons run on click, also making the init method static and this seems to have cleared up the issue.  Do you think this would be the best solution to that problem?   If you want to write an answer I will accept it.  Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options arrays in the Menu and Settings class are initially null and not given a valid reference until the `init()` is called. Are you trying to access the array before the method is called? Consider fixing this first. Perhaps the init code needs to be part of class's constructors?

Other suggestions:

- Your Mouse class has *state* and thus all that static code should be instance code.
- The Fonts class on the other hand looks to be a "utility" class, one which has no states nor methods which set or change state, so static methods seem to be OK there.
- Your Button class has a name clash with `java.awt.Button`. To avoid confusing others or *your future self*, consider changing its name to one that doesn't match a core Java class.
- Rather than re-draw each time Button's render is called, consider creating and storing BufferedImages using a lazy initiation tactic and then displaying.
- Your game loop does not appear to be following Swing threading rules, and this can lead to intermittent and hard to debug exceptions being thrown.
- You seem to be mixing AWT with Swing, a risky thing to do if you aren't very careful.